# Passar array de objetos Json para o Controller C# .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, .net

Preciso fazer um post, e até agora estou tentando fazer por AJAX para mandar um objeto para o Controller, mas estou com problema para receber o objeto.

### View/html:

```html
<select name="Servers" id="servers" multiple>
  <option value='{ "Id": "1", "Site": "234", "Tecnologia" : "89" }'>Server 1</option>
  <option value='{ "Id": "12", "Site": "21", "Tecnologia" : "12" }'>Server 2</option>
  <option value='{ "Id": "45", "Site": "332", "Tecnologia" : "56" }'>Server 3</option>
</select>
```

### Javascript/Jquery:

```js
var servers = [];

$("#myForm select:selected").each(function(i){ 
   servers.push(JSON.parse($(this).val()));
 }); 
 
var model = {
  "Nome": "qualquer nome aqui",
  "Servers": servers 
} 

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/Home/Add",
       data: model,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
           //Qualquer código aqui
       }
});
```

```js
public class EmpresaModel
{
    public string Nome { get;set; }           // Nome está vindo preenchido
    public List<ServerModel> Servers { get;set; }  // Como faço para isso vir preenchido?
}

public class ServerModel
{
    public string Id { get;set; }
    
    public string Site { get;set; }
    
    public string Tecnologia { get;set; }
}
```

Minha dúvida seria como eu faço para pegar essa lista de objetos que eu criei via ajax pelo model no controller? O nome esta vindo e preenchendo no model, porém a lista não. Algo como isso:

```js
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Add(EmpresaModel model)
{
    //codigo aqui 
}
```

OBS: Código feito agora só para exemplo, podendo ter erro de digitação ou algo do tipo.

Comment: O problema é que a sua `EmpresaModel` espera um atributo chamado `Servers` e você está enviando um JSON com `Servidores`. Outro detalhe que não foi apresentado é a versão do .Net MVC que você está usando, se for uma recente adicione o `FromBody` uma vez que se trata de um `POST`... ex.: public JsonResult `Add([FromBody]EmpresaModel model)`

Answer (score 1):

Seu código tem algumas coisas micro-coisas que somando fazem ele não rodar, mas vamos lá:
Primeiro:

```
<select name="Servers" id="servers" multiple>
  <option value='{ "Id": "1", "Site": "234", "Tecnologia" = "89" }'>Server 1</option>
  <option value='{ "Id": "12", "Site": "21", "Tecnologia" = "12" }'>Server 2</option>
  <option value='{ "Id": "45", "Site": "332", "Tecnologia" = "56" }'>Server 3</option>
</select>
```

Os values da sua view não estão no padrão "Chave":"Valor", observe que Tecnologia está utilizando o símbolo "=".

Segundo, não sou nenhum expert em jquery mas essa parte aqui o seu seletor está pegando o selected do select, não deveria ser do option? Testei com option e deu certo.

```
$("#myForm select:selected").each(function(i){  ///deveria ser option:selected
   servers.push(JSON.parse($(this).val()));
 });
```

Terceiro, seu model não tem os nomes do seu objeto, então não mapeiam quando chegam no controller:

```
var model = {
  "Nome": "qualquer nome aqui",
  "Servidores": servers    //aqui a chama deveria ser "Servers": servers para se igualar a sua entidade.
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta cara. Desculpa, a questão do '=' foi digitação, não estou com acesso ao código então simulei um exemplo de cabeça. A mesma coisa dos nomes, editei lá pra arrumar. Sobre o JQUERY ele está funcionando sim ele cria os objetos de forma certa, tanto que o resto dos atributos ele atribui normalmente no model. O meu problema está nesse mapeamento que vc disse, pois como faço para um objeto JSON conseguir ser mapeado em uma List<model> ? Eu provavelmente preciso mudar isso pra não ser uma lista, ai que estou me perdendo.

Comment: Ao meu ver sua lógica está correta. Tanto é que quando fiz essas alteraçõezinhas que te passei eu recebi a lista no meu controller normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo tenta assim:

Você tem que chamar esse método: JSON.stringify(model).

```js
var servers = [];

$("#myForm select:selected").each(function(i){ 
   servers.push(JSON.parse($(this).val()));
 }); 
 
var model = {
  "Nome": "qualquer nome aqui",
  "Servers": servers 
} 

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/Home/Add",
       data: JSON.stringify(model),
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
           //Qualquer código aqui
       }
});
```